# Increase TMP size Centos 6.5 whm/cpanel

Tags: centos, tmp

I'd like to increase it from 2G to 10G

Using `CENTOS 6.5 WHM 11.40.1 (build 11)`

I have tried:

```
#vi /scripts/securetmp
and looked for a line like “my $tmpdsksize”
```

its not there.
But this is what is in my securetmp file:

```
#!/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/bin/perl
# cpanel – scripts/securetmp Copyright(c) 2012 cPanel, Inc.
# All rights Reserved.
# copyright@cpanel.net http://cpanel.net
# This code is subject to the cPanel license. Unauthorized copying is prohibited
use strict;
use Cpanel::SafeFile ();
use Cpanel::OSSys ();
use Cpanel::Filesys ();
use Cpanel::DiskLib ();
use Getopt::Long;
use Cpanel::Logger ();
use Cpanel::SafeRun::Errors ();
use Cpanel::SafeRun::Simple ();
my $logger = Cpanel::Logger->new();
$| = 1;
if ( -e ‘/var/cpanel/version/securetmp_disabled’ ) {
print “[securetmp] Disabled per /var/cpanel/version/securetmp_disabled\n”;
exit;
}
my $system = $^O;
my $has_loop_device = 0;
“/scripts/securetmp” 681L, 21312C
```

I have also looked at `fstab`:

```
#
# /ereated by anaconda on Thu Sep  5 18:17:50 2013
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
UUID=bc5bb634-c602-471b-a3ee-1132e6452b8e       /       ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0        1       1
UUID=fb65c3c8-8e5c-48f5-93e7-f78fc5e8f75f /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=3387fdc6-572d-485e-8d74-74e8809aede8       /disk2  ext4    usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0        1       2
UUID=b0d8f329-1dec-4ef1-88d6-9ec6911a9615 /tmp                    ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=cb5116b4-9356-41c8-8777-3440bd0f88bb swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/tmp             /var/tmp                    ext3    defaults,bind,noauto        0 0
~
~
~
"fstab" 18L, 1067C
```

Here's my `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       455G   29G  403G   7% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1       243M   82M  148M  36% /boot
/dev/sdb1       459G  198M  435G   1% /disk2
/dev/sda3       2.0G   68M  1.9G   4% /tmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not familiar enough with cpanel to know why it would have anything to do with growing a partition. This is standard advice for any system using phyiscal partitions instead of [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29).

Think of physical partitions like songs on a record. To increase the partition boundary of /tmp which is on partition 3, you will move the end boundary across where partition 4 starts. Hopefully, you can understand why this would be a bad thing.

What you would need to do is create a new partition -- partition 6 after the last one, and mount this to /tmp. This will require you to have 10G free unallocated space. We'll need to see `fdisk -l` to know if you do or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Aaron.  I was doing some operations with mysql and ran out of space which started this whole issue.  In the end I decided on switching the tmpdir of mysql to a ramdisk and just leaving the tmp directory alone for now.